# How to avoid implementing methods repeatedly for identical classes?

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint, interface

I'm calling the Sharepoint 2007 `Lists` web service like this:

```
class ListUpdater
{
    public void update(ListWS.Lists listService,XmlNode xNode)
    {
        listService.UpdateListItems("myListName", xNode);
    }
}
```

Because we're migrating to Sharepoint 2013, I need to change this method to:

```
class ListUpdater
{
    public void update(ListWS_2013QA.Lists listService,XmlNode xNode)
    {
        listService.UpdateListItems("myListName", xNode);
    }
}
```

where `ListWS_2013QA` is the web service at the new URL.

However, I don't want to have to change this everywhere that an instance of the web service is declared, especially if I might have to change the web service multiple times over the application's lifetime.  I was thinking about having an interface `IListService` so that I could rewrite the method as:

```
class ListUpdater
{
    public void update(IListService listService,XmlNode xNode)
    {
        listService.UpdateListItems("myListName", xNode);
    }
}
```

But then for each version of the web service, I'd have to implement the interface with a wrapper that implements every method of `Lists` that I use in my code, like so:

```
class ListsWrapper_2013QA:IListService
{
    ListWS_2013QA.Lists listService;

    public XmlNode DoSomething(string listName, XmlNode listProperties, XmlNode newFields, XmlNode updateFields, XmlNode deleteFields, string listVersion)
    {
        return listService.UpdateList(listName, listProperties, newFields, updateFields, deleteFields, listVersion);
    }

    public XmlNode UpdateListItems(string listName, XmlNode updates)
    {
        return listService.UpdateListItems(listName, updates);
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can take advantage of the fact that `ListWS.Lists` and `ListWS_2013QA` already have the same methods, so I don't have to write an extensive wrapper class every time I want to use the `Lists` service from a different URL?

Comment: So where exactly are you getting the error message in your title at in your code?

Comment: @steve, the title was from another issue that I resolved before posting, and I forgot to change it when I posted this issue.  I'll change it now.

Comment: @juharr, see my reply to Steve's comment.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a class, that inherits IListService, and use it as a base class for your ListWrapper classes.